# ruby operationin where method

Tags: ruby, methods, operators

I have this code so what I am trying to do is if I typed the first name or the last name in the search it will result any of first or last

```
   def self.search_by(search_term)
           where(["LOWER(first_name) LIKE :search_term", 
                  {search_term: "%#{search_term.downcase}%" } ]
                ) || where(["LOWER(last_name) LIKE :search_term", 
                  {search_term: "%#{search_term.downcase}%" } ]
   end


<%= form_for "", url: members_path, class: "navbar-form navbar-left", role: "search", method: :get do %>
            <div id="tfheader">
              <%= text_field_tag :search, @search_term  ,id: "search",class: "tftextinput", size: "21", maxlength: "120" %>
              <input type="submit" value="Search" class="tfbutton">
              <div class="tfclear"></div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
```

Ex:

- First_name    Last_name
- John          Smeth
- Salma         Hayek

if I type in the text area john it will give me the whole row or if I typed hayek it also give me the whole row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logical disjunction should be done in the query, that said, on DB level, not on ruby one:

```
def self.search_by(search_term)
  where(
    "LOWER(first_name) LIKE :search_term OR LOWER(last_name) LIKE :search_term",
    search_term: "%#{search_term.downcase}%"
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

def self.search_by(search_term)

```
    where("first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:search_term]}%", "%#{params[:search_term]}%")
```

end